# Nested React Native Navigation doesn't show up

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

i'm currently working on a React Native App, it has two Main Screens, the main navigator is a Tab Navigator. The second main screen has its own NativeStack Navigator.
My Problem is, that the Second Navigator doesn't show anything. I just get a empty screen.

Second Screen Code:

```js
import {DataTable, Header, Screen} from '../../components';
import {
  NativeStackNavigationProp,
  createNativeStackNavigator,
} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, ViewStyle} from 'react-native';

import {EditorCreate} from '../Editor/Create';
import React from 'react';
import {useDatabase} from '../../data';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

type TProps = NativeStackNavigationProp<{}>;
const ReportStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

interface IStyle {
  container: ViewStyle;
  header: ViewStyle;
  dataList: ViewStyle;
  dataControls: ViewStyle;
}

/**
 * @description Report Bildschirm
 * @author OliverKarger
 * @param {IProps} props
 * @return {React.FC}
 */
export function ReportScreen(props: TProps) {
  const data = useDatabase({query: 'SELECT * FROM ENTRIES'}).data;
  const navHook = useNavigation();
  const style = StyleSheet.create<IStyle>({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    header: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    dataList: {
      flex: 4,
      // backgroundColor: 'red',
      width: '100%',
      height: '85%',
    },
    dataControls: {
      flex: 1,
      // backgroundColor: 'green',
      flexDirection: 'row',
    },
  });

  /**
   * @description Verarbeitet den "Edit Button" Klick
   * @author OliverKarger
   * @param {any} itemId Item Index
   */
  function editItemButton(itemId: any) {
    navHook.navigate('Editor', {action: 'edit', itemId: itemId});
  }

  /**
   * @description Report Area Funktion
   * @author OliverKarger
   * @return {React.FC}
   */
  function reportArea(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <View style={style.dataList}>
        <ScrollView>
          <DataTable
            editItemButton={editItemButton}
            data={data}
            style={{flex: 1}}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Screen style={style.container}>
      <Header />
      <ReportStack.Navigator initialRouteName='create'>
        <ReportStack.Screen name='reportarea' component={reportArea} />
        <ReportStack.Screen name='create' component={EditorCreate} />
      </ReportStack.Navigator>
    </Screen>
  );
}
```

Code of the Main Navigator:

```js
import {EditorScreen, HomeScreen, ReportScreen} from './screens';

import {Header} from './components';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

// import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

// import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

/**
 * @description Haupt Klasse, enthält primären App Code
 * @return {React.FC}
 */
export default function App() {


  Icon.loadFont();
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, marginTop: '15%'}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({route}) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
              const iconName: string = '';
              if (route.name === 'Home') {
                if (focused) {
                  return <Icon name='home' size={28} />;
                } else {
                  return <Icon name='user' size={28} />;
                }
              }
              if (route.name === 'Report') {
                if (focused) {
                  return <Icon name='folderopen' size={28} />;
                } else {
                  return <Icon name='folder1' size={28} />;
                }
              }
              return <Icon name={iconName} size={28} />;
            },
            headerShown: false,
          })}
          initialRouteName='Home'>
          <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen
            name='Report'
            options={{title: 'Übersicht'}}
            component={ReportScreen}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Greetings,
Oliver

Answer (score -1):

For anyone with the same problems, see: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3333#issuecomment-359740246

The problem was that the parent container had `alignItems: 'center'` as a style attribute assigned, which was causing the issue.